# Do you have to sanitize input in JS if only used for internal check

Tags: javascript, sanitization

I have a JS script on my page which checks document.referrer for a specific URL. If it exists then it changes a button on the page. I can't do it server side because of Varnish caching.

Do I need to sanitize document referrer and if so how?

I know you have to sanitize any user input server side or if you're printing out HTML from user input. Do you also need to do it if you're running checks on it?

If so will a basic function like encodeURIComponent suffice or do I need to create a bunch of manual escapes to strip characters?

```
  if(document.referrer.contains('mywebsite.com/url')){
      button.replaceWith(button2);
  };
```

Comment: Users can take control of the referrer value so you shouldn't trust it to be accurate or safe. It's not really a reliable way to determine anything in particular.

Comment: @Pointy It's not determining anything important, it's just a usability factor. It decides whether to display a back button or a hyperlink button. If the user takes control of it, then they probably don't care about normal functionality anyway! Plus the safety is what I'm asking about.

Comment: OK then; I was just being pedantic :)

Comment: @Pointy Always worth checking. I could easily be an idiot :)